# Weird results in Javascript math?

Tags: javascript, forms

I made this form to calculate points depending on user input.

Maximum points possible is 105 but the result given is 97.

To get maximum points the selections are:

- 21-49
- Phd or Masters & 17 years
- 6.5+
- 7.5+
- 6.5+
- 6.5+
- 4 Years or more
- Yes
- A master's or PhD and completed at least 17 years of full time studies
- Yes, more than two years post secondary after the age of 17
- Worked full time in Canada for at least a year
- Yes

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
<input name="pnt" type="hidden" value=" points">
<input name="rsn" type="hidden" value=" -not eligible">
<input name="rsy" type="hidden" value=" -eligible">
<label>Age</label>
<select name='g'>
<option value='' >Select One</option>
<option value='0' >Less than 17</option>
<option value='2' >17</option>
<option value='4' >18</option>
<option value='6' >19</option>
<option value='8' >20</option>
<option value='10' >21-49</option>
<option value='8' >50</option>
<option value='6' >51</option>
<option value='4' >52</option>
<option value='2' >53</option>
<option value='0' >54+</option>
</select>
<label>Education</label><select name='a'>
<option value='' selected='selected'>Select one</option>
<option value='0' >No High School</option>
<option value='5' >Secondary School</option>
<option value='12' >One Year Diploma, apprenticeship AND 12 years full time study</option>
<option value='15' >One Year Diploma, apprenticeship AND 13 years full time study</option>
<option value='15' >Bachelors Degree from University AND 13 years full time study</option>
<option value='20' >2 year diploma AND 14 years full time study</option>
<option value='20' >2 year bachelor&#039;s degree from university AND 14 years full time study</option>
<option value='22' >3 year diploma AND 15 years full time study</option>
<option value='22' >2 bachelor degrees from university and 15 years full time study</option>
<option value='25' >PhD or Masters &amp; 17 years full time study</option>
</select>
<h3><strong>Primary Language</strong></h3>
<label>Speaking</label>
<select name="c">
<option value='' >Select One</option>
<option value='4' >6.5+</option>
<option value='2' >5.5 – 6.0</option>
<option value='1' >4.0 – 5.0</option>
<option value='0' >Less than 4.0</option>
</select>
<label>Listening</label>
<select name="d">
<option value='' selected='selected'>Select One</option>
<option value='4' >7.5+</option>
<option value='2' >5.5 – 7.0</option>
<option value='1' >4.5 – 5.0</option>
<option value='0' >Less than 4.5</option>
</select>
<label>Reading</label>
<select name="e">
<option value='' >Select One</option>
<option value='4' >6.5+</option>
<option value='2' >5.0 – 6.0</option>
<option value='1' >3.5 – 4.5</option>
<option value='0' >Less than 3.5</option>
</select>
<label>Writing</label>
<select name='f'>
<option value='' >Select One</option>
<option value='4' >6.5+</option>
<option value='2' >5.5 – 6.0</option>
<option value='1' >4.0 – 5.0</option>
<option value='0' >Less than 4.0</option>
</select>
<h3><strong>Work</strong></h3>
<label>Work Experience</label>
<select name="b">
<option value=''>Select One</option>
<option value='0' >Less than 1 year</option>
<option value='15' >1 Year</option>
<option value='17' >2 Years</option>
<option value='19' >3 Years</option>
<option value='21' >4 Years or more</option>
</select>

<label>Arranged Employment</label>
<select name="l">
<option value=''>Select One</option>
<option value='10'>Yes</option>
<option value='0'>No</option>
</select>

<h3><strong>Adaptability</strong></h3>
<label>Spouse&#039;s Education</label>
<select name="h">
<option value='' >Select One</option>
<option value='0' >Secondary School</option>
<option value='3' >One Year Diploma, apprenticeship AND 12 years full time study</option>
<option value='3' >Bachelors Degree from University AND 13 years full time study</option>
<option value='4' >A two-year diploma, trade certificate or apprenticeship or university degree at the bachelor's level and completed at least 14 years of full-time or full-time equivalent studies</option>
<option value='4' >A three-year diploma, trade certificate or apprenticeship (not university) and completed at least 15 years of full-time or full-time equivalent studies</option>
<option value='4' >Two or more university degrees at the bachelor's level and completed at least 15 years of full-time or full-time equivalent studies</option>
<option value='5' >A master's or Ph.D. and completed at least 17 years of full-time or full-time equivalent studies</option>
<option value='0' >No Education</option>
</select>

<label>Applicant OR Spouse has studied in Canada</label>
<select name='i'>
<option value='5'>Yes, more than two years post secondary after the age of 17.</option>
<option value='0'>Yes, but for less than two years</option>
<option value='0'>No</option>
</select>
<label>Applicant OR Spouse has worked in Canada</label>
<select name="j">
<option value='' selected='selected'>Select One </option>
<option value='5'>Worked full-time in Canada for at least one year</option>
<option value='0'>Yes, but for less than 1 year</option>
<option value='0'>No</option>
</select>
<label>Applicant or Spouse has Family in Canada</label>
<select name="k">
<option value='' selected='selected'>Select One</option>
<option value='5'>Yes</option>
<option value='0'>No</option>
</select>
<INPUT NAME="calc" VALUE="Calculate" TYPE="button" onClick="compute(this.form)">
<input name="rslt" type="text" style="font-size: 50px" value="" size="20" readonly="readonly">
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- hide this script from old browsers
function compute(form)
{
var a = parseInt(form.a.value);
var b = parseInt(form.b.value);
var c = parseInt(form.c.value);
var d = parseInt(form.d.value);
var e = parseInt(form.e.value);
var f = parseInt(form.f.value);
var g = parseInt(form.g.value);
var h = parseInt(form.h.value);
var i = parseInt(form.i.value);
var j = parseInt(form.j.value);
var k = parseInt(form.k.value);
var l = parseInt(form.l.value);
f = (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+j+k+l);

form.rslt.value = f;
}

// done hiding from old browsers -->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please re-post this question, but: A) use http://jsfiddle.net/ to post the example code, and (more importantly) B) tell us what the problem is (what you expect, what you actually see).

Comment: The maximum is *102*, not 105!

Comment: I triple-checked, and the maximum points possible is 102, not 105.  @David Wolever, I thought the question was clear enough.  He's a live example: http://jsbin.com/adoli4

Comment: @strager: ah, that's true. I guess I missed it because the first paragraph didn't have any punctuation.

Comment: It doesn't look like it matters here, but as a general rule you should always specify a radix when calling `parseInt`, because otherwise the function will try to be helpful and will sometimes treat your input as an octal or hexadecimal string rather than a decimal string.  Better yet, this behavior's not consistent across browsers.  So I'd recommend using `parseInt(str, 10)` instead of just `parseInt(str)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is missing "i"

> f = (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+j+k+l);

(also, the max appears to be 102 to me)

Comment: oh, why do i keep missing these small things! thanks a lot (and yea there was an error in the values)

Comment: There's never any substitute for another pair of eyes. After a while we all see what should be there, not what is there ;-)